# Clustering Loop Python

Tags: python

I am clustering a data set in python using kmeans. Before I clustered the data set, I determined the optimal number of clusters using an elbow curve.

The optimal number of clusters was 5. So after kmeans clustered the dataset, I had 5 different clusters.

So here’s my question. Now that I have 5 different clusters, I would like to cluster those 5 clusters again so that I can get smaller clusters. Once I have smaller clusters for each one of those 5 clusters, I would like to cluster those smaller clusters again. I would like to repeat this until I have only about 20 points in each cluster. The dataset has 1,000,000 + observations.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to build a clustering loop? Is there a completely different better way to do this? I know this isn’t a specific coding question, but I’d love to hear some thoughts.

Comment: "The optimal number of clusters was 5." Why are you clustering beyond the optimal number of clusters? Why not just use `k = 1_000_000 / 20` from the beginning?

Comment: Well the optimal number of clusters for the entire data set is 5. But that number will change every time we reduce the dataset. So each of the 5 clusters will have their own optimal number which can be found via elbow curve. Problem is it will take forever to branch out until I get the desired cluster size. That’s why I was wondering whether there’s a way to loop everything.

Comment: Can you provide your initial code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to provide some pseudocode since you didn't provide any details about yout code (which you should, by the way):

```
def cluster_until_20(data):
    if data.size() == 20:
        return data
    clusters = kmeans(data, 5)
    if any size of cluster in clusters != 20:
        return [cluster_until_20(cluster) for cluster in clusters]
    return clusters
```

The key is using recursion with a list comprehension, that will go "deeper" in recursion as long as the size of data is != 20